# How do you unlock a locked alias file in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal

- There is no sharing and permissions tab present in the "get info" pane.
- Using "sudo chflags nouchg [filename]" on the file has no effect though also throws no errors in the terminal
- Trying to delete the file or rename it or in any other way change it seems to be prevented because it is locked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to boot into single-user mode. See [this thread](http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=2667) on the forums at macosxhints.com